# How to Get Users Relationship Status In Facebook Register on website

Tags: php, facebook

i am using facebook register API for my site

its here

now its showing some 2 custom fields and all other default fields
i want to show  a user relationship status also

can anyone please tell me how to do that

Answer (score 1):

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/ for the docs

You'll either want to use the regular API to retrieve the fields once the user has signed up,  and you have an `access_token` for them, or use custom fields on the signup form itself  - in which case just add the fields to the `fields` parameter following the instructions in the documentation